# How to get my div to display selected youtube api content?

Tags: jquery, html, css, youtube

I had to repost because nobody gave me the answer I wanted.

I am trying to get to when the user clicks on the button below that video it displays that video in a popup.   However, it only shows the same video on each button click.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

  <title>slider demo</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js-image-slider.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body >
 <style>
#myDIV {
    display: none;
}
  .display {
  display: block;
}
.span2:focus ~ .alert {
  display: none;
}
.span3:focus ~ .myDIV {
  display: block;
   padding: 20px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
}/*
.alert{display:none;}
*/
.alert {
  display:none;
}
.showdiv{

  display: block;
   padding: 20px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
}
#video ~ #myDIV{
  z-index: 1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-md-12 display"></div>
<p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>

<p id ="mydiv"onclick="myFunction()">Try it</p>

<div id="myDIV "><div class="display">
This is my DIV element.
</div>
</div>


<p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>
<div id = "results"></div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
        x.style.color = 'blue';
        x.style.position = 'absolute';
        x.style.top = '20px';
        x.style.left = '100px';
        x.style.background = 'red';


    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document.ready(function(){
      $('#select').click(function(){

 $('#myDIV').append('<p>Hello world</p>');
      });


   });)
</script>
<script>
var channelName='ajaxkm';

$(document).ready(function()
{
  $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels",
  {
    part: 'contentDetails',
    forUsername: channelName,
    key: ''},
    function(data)
    {
      $.each(data.items,function(i,item)
      {
      console.log(item);
      pid=item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
      getVids(pid);
      })


    }
);
function getVids(pid){
    $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems",
  {
    part: 'snippet',
    maxResults: 10,
    playlistId: pid,

    key: ''},
    function(data)
    {
      var output;
      $.each(data.items,function(i,item)
      {
      console.log(item);
      videTitle=item.snippet.title;
      videoId = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
      videoDescription = item.snippet.description;
      output2='<div class="col-md-4 display"><iframe src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/'+videoId+'\"></iframe><br><p id="show">'+videoDescription+'</p><span id ="span3" tabindex ="0"><p id ="select" onclick="myFunction()" > Discription of Video</p></span><p id="myDIV"><iframe id ="video" src =\"//www.youtube.com/embed/'+videoId+'\" ></iframe>'+videoDescription+ '</p></div>';



   //   output='<div class="col-md-4"><iframe id="youtube" src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/'+videoId+'\"></iframe><p onclick="myFunction()"><span tabindex ="0"> Try it</span></p></div>';
   //   v = '<iframe class ="display" src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/'+videoId+'\"></iframe>';
      textout= videoDescription;
      //append to results listStyleType
      $('#results').append(output2);
    //  $('#myDIV').append(v);
      $('#text').append(textout);
      })


    }
);
}

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
jquery html css iframe youtube
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried rendering the button such that the link to the video is updated when it's clicked? It looks like the link is not being updated on click, which is why you are only seeing the same video.

something like...

```
var button = $("<button></button>")
  .text("Add to Watchlist")
  .click(function() {
    getVids(pid)
    render();
  })
```

and what goes into render() is the code that generates the request to youtube. (ie .get)

Then to add the button I would append it to div, in the same place where you have the div line.

```
$('#myDIV').append(button)
```

Comment: I tried it but it when I click on the button it just duplicates the button